# Find number and replace + 1

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have a large file with a list of objects that have an incrementing page # ie

```
[
{page: 1},
{page: 2},
{page: 3}
]
```

I can find each instance of `page: #` with `page: (\d)` in vscode's ctrl+f finder. How would I replace each of these numbers with # + 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to perform arithmetic with regex. I use LINQPad to execute these small kind of scripts. An example of how I would do it is in the c# program below.

```
void Main()
{
    var basePath = @"C:\";

    // Get all files with extension .cs in the directory and all its subdirectories.
    foreach (var filePath in Directory.GetFiles(basePath, "*.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        // Read the content of the file.
        var fileContent = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

        // Replace the content by using a named capture group.
        // The named capture group allows one to work with only a part of the regex match.
        var replacedContent = Regex.Replace(fileContent, @"page: (?<number>[0-9]+)", match => $"page: {int.Parse(match.Groups["number"].Value) + 1}");

        // Write the replaced content back to the file.
        File.WriteAllText(filePath, replacedContent);
    }
}
```

I also took the liberty of changing your regex to the one below.

```
page: (?<number>[0-9]+)

page:  matches with "page: " literally.
(?<number> is the start of a named capture group called number. We can then use this group during replacement.
[0-9]+ matches a number between 0 and 9 one to infinite times. This is more specific than using \d as \d also matches other number characters.
The + makes it match more than on digit allowing for the number 10 and onwards.
) is the end of a named capture group.
```

Answer (score 11):

It can be done rather easily in vscode using one of emmet's built-in commands:

```
Emmet: Increment by 1
```

1. Use your regex to find all the `page: \d+` in your file.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> to select all those occurrences.
3. Trigger the `Emmet: Increment by 1` command.

Here is a demo:

[image: Emmet:Increment buy 1]

Answer (score 0):

You could do that in Ruby as follows.

```
FileIn  = "in"
FileOut = "out"
```

File let's construct a sample file (containing `37` characters).

```
File.write FileIn, "[\n{page: 1},\n{page: 2},\n{page: 33}\n]\n"
  #=> 37
```

We may now read the input file `FileIn`, convert it and write it to a new file `FileOut`.

```
File.write(FileOut, File.read(FileIn).
     gsub(/\{page: (\d+)\}/) { "{page: #{$1.next}}" })
```

Let's look at what's be written.

```
puts File.read(FileOut)
[
{page: 2},
{page: 3},
{page: 34}
]
```

I've *gulped* the entire file, made the changes in memory and spit out the modified file. If the original file were large this could be easily modified to read from and write to the files line-by-line.

Answer (score 0):

Adding another answer as it is significantly different than the other.  I wrote an extension [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview)  which makes it easy to do math in a find in a file.

In this case with this keybinding (in your `keybindings.json` file):

```
{
  "key": "alt+r",                  // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {      
    "find": "page: (\\d)",
    "replace": "page: $${ return $1 + 1 }$$",
    "isRegex": true
}
```

[That could also be a setting in your `settings.json` file if you wish with slightly different syntax of course.]

The `$${ return $1 + 1 }$$` represents a javascript operation. Here 1 will be added to capture group 1 from the `find` regex.

Within the `$${ ... }$$` almost any javascript operation can be inserted.  There are many examples in the repo.

[image: math on a find]